# Place a picture next to my H1 text no matter what the width of the text is

Tags: html, css

As you can see on the picture below, I placed an arrow image at the head on my H1 text.
I did that by playing with margin right and top. It's working but the issue is that if I modify the H1 text then I would have to play with the margin right again.
Is there a way to place the arrow at the end of the H1 text no matter what the width of the text is?
Many thanks,

[image]

```
<div class="block">
    <h1><span>H1 HEADER EN UIUIUIU MOTS</span> KKJKJJKJJKJKJdJKJJK</h1><img class="arrow" src="images/arrow-down.png" alt="arrow">
  </div>
  <div class="block clear fish shadow">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 980px;   
}

.arrow{
margin-right: 290px;
float: right;
margin-top: -45px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, if the image is to be directly after the text, you can use a pseudo-element (:after)

```
h1:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  width:50px;
  height: inherit;
   background-image: url(path_to/images/arrow-down.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vxmws)

Answer (score 5):

As the image you're using looks like it's for decorative purposes, I would use a `background`  on the `h1` instead, position it to the far right, and use `padding-right` to push the image away from the `h1`. So for example, try:

CSS:

```
h1 {
    background: url(images/arrow-down.png) no-repeat right center;
    padding-right: 40px; /* tweak this */
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/peasandwell/pen/veLwu)

As for those who are suggesting using the `:after` pseudo selector, I would strongly advise against doing so, as :after [is not great on older IE browsers](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after/) (plus it's a needlessly complicated solution for a simple task).

Answer (score 3):

Can you not put the image in the background of the h1 and use background-position to align it to the right?

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vyDBF)

Comment: specially as :after selector does not work in IE < 7 and needs special doctype in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CSS` pseudo-element `:after` [(only for iE8 and +)](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3aafter) :

HTML :

```
<h1>Hi there !</h1>
```

And your `CSS` code (supposing your image is `50px * 50px`) :

```
h1 {
    background: #eee;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}

h1:after {
    background: url('images/arrow-down.png') bottom right no-repeat;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
```

The `H1` `padding-right` must be equal to your image `CSS` `width`.

Or simply use :

```
 h1 {
        background: url('images/arrow-down.png') bottom right no-repeat;
        padding-right: 50px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you also can solve that issue with some jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    arrowMargin();
    function arrowMargin() {
        $('.block img').css('margin-left', $('.block h1').width());
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        arrowMargin();
    });

});
```

you have to delete your margin-right in the css.

greetings Timotheus

Answer (score -1):

You could give the H1 tag a class and use the css 'after' selector:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp